# Illegal string offset 'name' php - Many Array into 1 Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

With the help of variable categories i have this array in which all the arrays are without key/default index , because of this when i do $categories as $category in foreach and when i echo $category['name'] it gives illegal sting offet.

using laravel blade

[image]

What can be the possible solution for this or should i validate array first?

Comment: The categories might be objects. Try using `$category->name` instead.

Comment: NO they are not and i already tried this then the error is trying to get the property of non object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your situation, and in my opinion, you are using the wrong variable to decode let me take your image as an example here.

```
    <?php

      $ex = [
     'result' => 'success',
       'categories' => [
      [
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'cat1',
    ],
    [
        'id'=>2, 
        'name'=>'cat21',
    ],
    [
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>'cat31',
    ],
  ]
];
echo "<pre>";
$res = json_encode($ex);
print_r(json_decode($res));
```

in this example, I just showed you that I have done json_encode and json_decode easily without any issue and the output of JSON is same as your example image.

[image]

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

The above code is in JSON format, convert to array first

for example

```
 $ex = {
         'result':"success",
         'categories':[{
              //your rest of the code
          }]
    }
    $data = json_decode($ex, TRUE);
//next use for each
     foreach($data as $key => $value)
     {
      //rest of your logic
     }
```

Comment: "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"